# How to graph power law normalized for specific parameters?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the type-II superconductors power law for different values of its parameters. I'm currently using the next code. But I want specific values for n, not an iteration, for example, n=1,3,5,15,25,50. Also I want to plot as: J/J0 vs E/E0, but can't manage to do it. I know it's kinda silly, but I can't find a way of doing it, having a little trouble with ":=" and "=" for plotting functions. Thanks in advance!

```
E0 = 4*10^-4;
  J0 = 1*10^3; 
  Elec[n_] := E0 (J/J0)^n

 Plot[Evaluate@Table[Elec[n], {n, 1, 25, 4}], {J, 0, J0}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=5", "n=9", "n=13", "n=17", "n=21"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

An example of the graph i'm looking:
[image]

Comment: Instead of `{n, 1, 25, 4}`, you can write a list over which to iterate `{n, {1, 3, 5, 15, 25, 50}}`

Comment: Thank you! Did not thought of that solution haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something closer to your desired result (using your definitions):

```
ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[{J/J0, Elec[n]/E0}, {n, {1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21}}],
  {J, 0, J0},

  (*AspectRatio to reproduce the ratio in your plot, and in Plot *)
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,

  (* adjust plot range, and prevent dots from being clipped*)
  PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  PlotLegends -> {"n = 1", "n = 5", "n = 9", "n = 13", "n = 17", "n = 21"},
  PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,
  (*MaxRecursion -> 0 turns off the adaptive sampling features, *)
  (*giving equally spaced mesh points*)
  MaxRecursion -> 0,

  (*Mesh -> All shows all the points used in the plotting*)
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> PointSize[0.015]
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Black] & /@ 
          {"J/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(0\)]\)", 
           "E/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(0\)]\)"})
]
```

[image: formatted parametric plot]

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot! Looks great. Also thanks for commenting the code.

Comment: @Santiago You are very welcome!